# How do I enable a vim color scheme?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to enable the github color scheme on vim.

I've downloaded the script from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2855 and copied it to `~/.vim/colors`.

Then I've opened vim and typed `:colo github`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I've also tried adding `colorscheme github` at the end of my `~/.vimrc` file, but that also doesn't seem to do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using vim in a terminal? That colorscheme is GUI-only.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the colorscheme script, you'll notice that it only contains `gui[fg|bg]=...` definitions; it is for graphical GVIM only, and doesn't provide definitions for (color) terminals.

Plugins like [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) can take the GUI color definitions and convert them to a closely matching 256-color `cterm` color palette for high-color terminals. This helps with colorschemes that otherwise only pick from the bland default 16-color terminal color palette, or only provide GUI color definitions.

Another approach is taken by [csexact](https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact), which modifies the (supported) terminal's palette to exactly match Vim's GUI colors.